# Using azure graph api not able to download ".eml" attachment from Email

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, email-attachments, microsoft-graph-mail

when I try to get attachments from outlook mail ".eml" file are not able to download.
response object has no contentBytes

```
{
    "@odata.context": "",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment",
    "id": "AAMkAGYzZDI2Nj......",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-03-08T11:41:38Z",
    "name": "EML Test.eml",
    "contentType": "message/rfc822",
    "size": 71087,
    "isInline": false
}
```

Other file types has contentBytes

```
{
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            "@odata.mediaContentType": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "id": "AAMkAGYzZDI2N....",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-03-07T13:12:52Z",
            "name": "Admins-07-02-202311_24.xls",
            "contentType": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
            "size": 42778,
            "isInline": false,
            "contentId": "f_ley9tj8o0",
            "contentLocation": null,
            "contentBytes": "0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPgADAP7/CQAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAMQAAAAAAAAAAEAAATwAAAAEAAAD+////AAAAADAAAAD////////////////////........"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this is an Item attachment you need to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#get-the-raw-contents-of-a-file-or-item-attachment so take the attachmentId from the first response you posted and construct a URL like

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAM.../attachments/AAM.../$value
```

which will then return the MIME content of the attached message